# Adobe-DTM, splitting referrer using custom script in Data Element

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

In Adobe DTM I have created a data element to capture the document.referrer information and splitting it into array and storing the 0 index of the array into a variable. The code looks like below:

```
var ref0 = document.referrer;
var taboola;
var trc;
var api;
var ref1;
var ref2;
if (taboola = ref0.includes("taboola.com"))
{
    if (trc = ref0.includes("trc"))
    {
        ref1 = ref0.split("/log")
        ref2 = ref1[0];
        return ref2;
    }
    else if(api = ref0.includes("api"))
    {
        ref1 = ref0.split("/recommendations")
        ref2 = ref1[0];
        return ref2;
    }
}
```

and then I created a page load rule with a condition that the URL should the parameter utm_source and value as taboola. Within this rule, I am passing the value of the data element into a conversion variable.

The report is not populating in Report and Analytics. The above code works perfectly fine in a browser console but not sure what is wrong with DTM.

Comment: I would add a console out in your page rule to test that the data element is returning the expected value. After that, it would depend on how you are using that value to report back to analytics.

Comment: @BrettAHale Thanks for the help! I can see the report in Analytics now. I guess there was some report suite latency issue.

Comment: Aha! that will do it :) There's a little clock icon at the top of most reports where you can see the expected latency of reports. That's handy when it comes to development.